# Infinite loop shell script not getting killed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to do some tasks in linux (benchmark test on mysql which will take upto 1 or 2 hour) using shell script and in the meantime itself, i need to run another script in parallel which would take output of the task in every 10 or 20 mins and write the output to a file. Now, once the task is finished, I would like to stop the second script and get the output. But its not happening. Here is what I did so far:

**taskscript** - Where I'm performing an 1 or 2 hr task

```
#!/bin/sh
#Here I'm doing some task which takes upto 1 hr
#For simulating test
sleep 10
echo "Task Finished" > "task.txt";
```

**infintequery** - Script which will take the output of task in parallel

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; 
do
sleep 10;
#Here I'm querying task result and store it to a an output file with timestamp
#For simulating test, just writing time only
echo $(date +"%m/%d %T") >> "infinite.txt";
done
```

**mainscript** - The main script which runs both the scripts in parallel

```
#!/bin/sh

sh ./taskscript 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid1=$!

sh ./infintequery 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid2=$!

wait $pid1
ret1=$?
wait $pid2
ret2=$?

if [ $ret1 -eq 0 ]
then 
   echo "Completed succesfully"
   kill $pid2
else
    echo "Failed to complete script"
fi
```

After I executing `./mainscript`, following was the output

- task.txt was generated after 10 seconds
- infinite.txt was appended with time every 10 seconds.
- The script never get finished and infinite.txt gets updated every 10
  seconds.

I want the mainscript to stop execution after taskscript was finished, but the mainscript was also not finishing and even after I give Ctrl-C, the infinite.txt is still getting updated.

So guys, please help me to solve this issue. What am I doing wrong here? I'm not that experianced in shell scripting, these codes are all taken from some posts in SO itself.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code here:

```
wait $pid1
ret1=$?
wait $pid2
```

will ensure it waits for both processes to finish and hence `mainscript` will never get to the `kill` statement.

That's because `infintequery` (I assume that was meant to be infinite but I'll spell it the same way you have) will never exit and `mainscript` will be forever waiting at the `wait $pid2` line.

If you just want to wait for `taskscript` to finish then kill off `infintequery`, use something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

sh ./taskscript 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid1=$!

sh ./infintequery 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid2=$!

wait $pid1
ret1=$?

kill $pid2
if [ $ret1 -eq 0 ]
then 
   echo "Completed successfully"
else
    echo "Failed to complete script"
fi
```

That will simply wait for `taskscript` to finish and then kill off `infintequery` regardless of whether `taskscript` was successful or not.

Of course, that's assuming `taskscript` has to be running before `infintequery` starts (the likely case since the latter will probably end up using some information from the former). If it *doesn't* have to be running first, you can simplify by not running it in the background:

```
#!/bin/sh

sh ./infintequery 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
pid2=$!

sh ./taskscript 1>/dev/null 2>&1
ret1=$?

kill $pid2
if [ $ret1 -eq 0 ]
then 
   echo "Completed successfully"
else
    echo "Failed to complete script"
fi
```

Comment: So could u pls advise me how to correct this. I'm not familiar with these stuff.

Comment: Thanks..that was perfect..I understood wait for pid2 cause my script to hang. But in ur last edited portion, there is no wait and so I cant use that form to get it work.It get finished immediately after executing.

Comment: @HRM, in the last code segment, there is no `wait $pid1` because it's not actually running in the background (the `&` has been removed). The main script will start it in the foreground meaning it will wait automatically for it to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Another soln without changing your main script and if not comfortable with wait and pids.
Add this line in loop in infintequery file.

```
if [ `grep "Task Finished" input | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then exit; fi
```